# How stop table verification in SQL query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi I have sql query like

```
declare @VersionNo varchar(30)
Set @VersionNo = '2007'

IF @VersionNo='2007'
     (Select name,type from [Table_2007])
else
    (Select name,type from [Table_2010])
```

Need to Query data from table where table name will change based on versionNo..

As you know, the above query returns the 'Invalid columnname or Invalid table' since either one table will not exists in both version..

So.. can any one give me an idea to stop table verification  in SQL query?

Comment: This is a very bad database design, if I might say.

Comment: (: this is not our DB design ,  we r just querying data from Microsoft s' SharePoint server

Comment: Out of curiosity, what do you mean by two different versions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
declare @VersionNo varchar(30)
Set @VersionNo = '2007'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)


IF @VersionNo='2007'
     set @sql = 'Select name,type from [Table_2007]'
else
    set @sql = 'Select name,type from [Table_2010]'

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

or if table names is match with version you can omit if statement like this

```
declare @VersionNo varchar(30)
Set @VersionNo = '2007'

declare @sql nvarchar(max)

set @sql = 'Select name,type from Table_'+@VersionNo 

exec sp_executesql @sql
```

Comment: You're welcome, if this is correct please make my post as 'Answer'

Comment: Oh yes...now only I have granted privilege (::.   is there any other way instead of Exec?

Comment: There is a check mark beside every answer and you can click on it

Comment: Yes.. I know Reza..but it says.. I don't have privilege to do.. it requires 15 points.. but now I have only 13...

Comment: OK @kombsh, no problem

Answer (score 0):

Although all the dynamic SQL code suggestions will work as expected, I'm not a fan of dynamic sql if it's not really needed. (Yes, it depends a lot on the situation, I know). 
Anyway, **I'm not sure what the problem is in the first place.** I'm currently running on SQL2012 but I'm pretty sure this has worked the same way in older versions for as long as I can remember.

When I run

```
create table [Table_2007] (name int, type int)
GO

declare @VersionNo varchar(30)
Set @VersionNo = '2007'

IF @VersionNo='2007'
     (Select name,type from [Table_2007])
else
    (Select name,type from [Table_2010])
```

This works perfectly. Off course it will give an error if you end up in the branch of the non-existing table, but no amount of dynamic sql is going to save you from that!?
I did some testing, and as you can see this works 'as expected' in each situation.

```
USE tempdb
GO
CREATE TABLE t_table1 (x int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, y varchar(max) NULL)
INSERT t_table1 VALUES (1, 'this is table 1')
GO
CREATE TABLE t_table2 (x int NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY, y varchar(max) NULL)
INSERT t_table2 VALUES (2, 'this is table 2')
GO
-- check if both exist
DECLARE @table_wanted varchar(30)
SELECT @table_wanted = 'table1'

IF @table_wanted = 'table1'
    SELECT * FROM t_table1
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM t_table2

GO
-- check if only first one exists (and is asked for)
DECLARE @table_wanted varchar(30)
SELECT @table_wanted = 'table1'

IF @table_wanted = 'table1'
    SELECT * FROM t_table1
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM t_table99
GO
-- check if only second one exists (and is asked for)
DECLARE @table_wanted varchar(30)
SELECT @table_wanted = 'table2'

IF @table_wanted = 'table99'
    SELECT * FROM t_table99
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM t_table2

GO
-- check if only first one exists (and we ask for the other one)
DECLARE @table_wanted varchar(30)
SELECT @table_wanted = 'table99'

IF @table_wanted = 'table1'
    SELECT * FROM t_table1
ELSE
    SELECT * FROM t_table99
```

PS: Another way around this problem would be to build a view that will have the same name in each database or server (or ... ?) but internally points to the right table depending of its context.